# Create an accurate millisecond timer that loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

After some research, I understand the most accurate way to create a timer in Javascript is to compare the elapsed time from a starting point using date.now() -as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307612/1972126) suggests.

```
var startTime = Date.now();

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
  var time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
  console.log(time);
}, 10);
```

This provides the accuracy I am looking for, but I am looking to make this timer reset itself after a certain value (let's say `var total = 12000`). This value is determined by the length of a video playlist (I am building a 'live' playhead for a video program) and is a variable.

I'm stuck how to go about this, as the counter is counting elapsed time from a certain point in time, it doesn't quite fit the logic of what I am looking for. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrap it in another setInterval that clears and resets the inner interval

Comment: I've tried that and it only starts the counter after a delay (in this case 3000ms):

var startTime = Date.now();

setInterval(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    var time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log(time);
  }, 10);
}, 3000);

Comment: you can't, the end. The JS spec itself explains why, but the tl;dr is that setTimeout does not have 1ms resolution. It will give you ~1ms for a few calls and will then drastically [throttle to ~4ms instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). But it sounds like you don't need a 1-after-1 ms timer at all, you just need ms-accuracter _interval measurement_, which `Date.now()` already lets you do.

Comment: correct -- an interval measurement which I need to reset after a certain value.

Comment: `var elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime) % playListLength;` ... and then you dont need any other special coding. ... A question: But how can you guarantee *ahead of time* when to "reset" as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans mentions, the resolution is not exact.

Comment: I thought about this solution and it's great in its simplicity -- but there is a crucial problem: if the playlist length increases (a video is added) while a person is watching, it means the live time will suddenly jump in value as the modulo value increases. I want to avoid this behaviour as it disrupts the live time for viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) at the end of your code to restart your [`.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), after the desired time has passed

```js
function runInterval (loopAfter) {
  var startTime = Date.now();

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    var time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log(time);
  }, 10);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    runInterval(loopAfter);
  }, loopAfter);
}

runInterval(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
let total = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (total === 12000) {
    total = 0;
    startTime = Date.now();
  } else {
    total++;
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    var time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
  }
  console.log(time);
}, 10);
```